# multi-column hibernate query to xhtml page

Tags: mysql, hibernate, xhtml

I am trying to do a multi-column query in hibernate, and I want to know how to map the results to the xhtml file (I'm using JSF/seam).

So, this is my hibernate query:

```
@Name("theusers")
@AutoCreate
@Scope(SESSION)
public class Users implements Serializable {
@In
private EntityManager entityManager;

String unameit;
public String getUnameit() {
    return unameit;
}
public void setUnameit(String unameit) {
this.unameit = unameit;
}

private List<Myuser[]> theusers;

public List<Myuser[]> getUsers(String uname) {
try {

        theusers = (List<Myuser[]>)entityManager.createQuery("SELECT username, lastname from Myuser where username = :uname")
    .setParameter("uname", uname)
        .getResultList();

    } catch(Exception e) {
        theusers = null;
    }
    return theusers;
    }
}
```

Basically I want to retrieve the username and lastName column from the table user_detail.
This is how I want to visualize it in 2 columns in xhtml:

```
<h:form id="un_form">
<p>Enter your username: <h:inputText id="unameit" value="#{theusers.unameit}" size="40"       /></p>
<p><h:commandButton value="Submit" /></p>
</h:form>

<h:dataTable value="#{theusers.getUsers(theusers.unameit)}" var="u">
<h:column>
<f:facet name="header">
User name
</f:facet>
#{u.getUserName()}
</h:column>
<h:column>
<f:facet name="header">
User last name
</f:facet>
#{u.getLastName()}
</h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

And finally Myuser.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user_detail")
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "obj_type", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING,   length = 255)
public abstract class Myuser { //implements Serializable {
@Id
public int id;
public String username;
public String firstname;
public String lastname;

@Column(name="id")
public int getId() {
        return id;
}

@Column(name = "username")
public String getUserName() {
        return username;
}

@Column(name = "firstName")
public String getFirstName() {
        return firstname;
}

@Column(name = "lastName")
public String getLastName() {
        return lastname;
}

public Myuser(int id, String username, String firstname, String lastname) {
    this.id = id;
    this.username = username;
    this.firstname = firstname;
    this.lastname = lastname;
}

public void setId( int id ) {
        this.id = id;
}

public void setFirstName( String firstname ) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
}

public void setLastName( String lastname ) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
}

public void setUserName( String username ) {
        this.username = username;
}
}
```

I keep getting an error. What could be wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Use `List<Myuser>` instead of `List<Myuser[]>`

Comment: Tried that, still gives errors.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is not returning a list of 'Myuser's it is returning a list of username's and lastname's

If you change your query to...

```
from Myuser where username = :uname
```

and change the return type to `List<Myuser>`

You will then return a list of Myusers that you can use in the datatable

Additionally you need to rework your backing bean and view a bit, the method getUsers needs to be called from the h:commandButton, this sets 'theusers' in your bean

```
@Name("theusers")
@AutoCreate
@Scope(SESSION)
public class Users implements Serializable {
@In
private EntityManager entityManager;

String unameit;
public String getUnameit() {
    return unameit;
}
public void setUnameit(String unameit) {
this.unameit = unameit;
}

private List<Myuser> theusers;

public void getUsers() {
        try {
            theusers = (List<Myuser>)entityManager.createQuery("from Myuser where username = :uname")
            .setParameter("uname", uname)
            .getResultList();

            }catch(Exception e) {
                theusers = null;
            }
        }
}
```

and your page...

```
<h:form id="un_form">
<p>Enter your username: <h:inputText id="unameit" value="#{theusers.unameit}" size="40"       /></p>
<p><h:commandButton action="#{theusers.getUsers}" value="Submit" /></p>
</h:form>

<h:dataTable value="#{theusers.theusers}" var="u">
<h:column>
<f:facet name="header">
User name
</f:facet>
#{u.getUserName()}
</h:column>
<h:column>
<f:facet name="header">
User last name
</f:facet>
#{u.getLastName()}
</h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

Comment: Still not working, this is what Myuser looks like: @Table(name="user_detail")
    public abstract class Myuser {
 @Id
 public int id;
    public String username;
    public String firstname;
    public String lastname;

 @Column(name="id")
 public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    ...

 public Myuser(int id, String username, String firstname, String lastname) {
  this.id = id;
  this.username = username;
  this.firstname = firstname;
  this.lastname = lastname;
 }
    ...

Comment: there were some more changes you need to make, I have added them above

Comment: 18:00:41,137 WARN  [JDBCExceptionReporter] SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
18:00:41,137 ERROR [JDBCExceptionReporter] Transaction is not active: tx=TransactionImple < ac, BasicAction: -3f39c9ff:b4fb:5362d1ae:87 status: ActionStatus.ABORT_ONLY >; - nested throwable: (javax.resource.ResourceException: Transaction is not active: tx=TransactionImple < ac, BasicAction: -3f39c9ff:b4fb:5362d1ae:87 status: ActionStatus.ABORT_ONLY >)

Comment: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /test/users.xhtml @20,52 value="#{theusers.theusers}": Property 'theusers' not found on type uk.ac.ebi.bioinvindex.services.Users_$$_javassist_seam_6

Comment: you need to add a getter for theusers

Comment: Property 'theusers' not found on type uk.ac.ebi.bioinvindex.services Thanks so much for being so helpful! :)

Comment: plus check the Myuser.java above plusI made the getter for theusers like so:  private List<Myuser> getTheusers() {
  return theusers;
 }

Comment: Ok can you post the full error from the console in your question?

Comment: This is the MySQL transaction: 11:43:27,865 INFO  [lifecycle] WARNING: FacesMessage(s) have been enqueued, but may not have been displayed.
sourceId=null[severity=(WARN 1), summary=(Transaction failed), detail=(Transaction failed)], the xhtml page comes up fine, but when I enter a username, it does nothing

Comment: However, the user_detail table in our mysql database has more columns then just forstname, lastname, username, etc.

Comment: also this on xhtml page: /test/users.xhtml: Method not found: [Ljava.lang.Object;@4d2a348e.getUsername()